# Why is TimeSpan.TotalHours not calculating correctly?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code:

```
DateTime PunchIn = DateTime.Parse("12/10/2015 5:06:00 PM");
DateTime PunchOut = DateTime.Parse("12/10/2015 5:30:00 PM");
double WorkedTime;
WorkedTime = (PunchOut - PunchIn).TotalHours;

MessageBox.Show(WorkedTime.ToString());
```

The value of WorkedTime should be 0.4 (24/60).

But as you can see from the following screenshot, the calculated value is 0.39999999...

[image: screenshot1]

But to make it even more confusing, the MessageBox displays the calculated value as 0.4

[image: screenshot2]

Can anyone help explain this seemingly bizarre behavior?

EDIT: If this is a "floating point inaccuracy", what is the work around so I can get the answer of 0.4 in my code?

Comment: Seems like a floating point precision bug.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples

Comment: @JamesGaunt not really a bug just the nature of floating point numbers

Comment: @MarcoFatica yes, fair point, we'll call it a "feature" then :)

Comment: `ToString()` delivers the default format in the given context. When you deal with variables where the string format matters (e.g., a number or a date), this behaviour might not be the one you want. Bottom line: never use `ToString()` without any argument when the format matters unless being completely sure that you know the format in the given context. In this case, you should input as argument the number of decimal positions to be displayed.

Comment: Change WorkedTime to decimal instead of double

Comment: @varocarbas, the first part of the question (why is the value 3.999999 and not the 'correct' answer of 4) is due to the nature of floating point numbers. The second part is due to string formatting.

Comment: @JamesGaunt OK. Good correction. I was focused on the second part :)

Comment: Anyone have a work around for the floating point precision bug?

Comment: american date format is stupid. just putting that out there. might as well be month/day/year second:hour:minute. but yeah.

Comment: @jgayetty--it's not really a bug, but simply the nature of using floating points.  Use decimal instead of double--decimals have significantly higher precision, and this might be sufficient to address the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many decimal numbers cannot be represented as binary floating point numbers without precision loss. Just like 1/3 cannot be represented as a finite decimal number.

What you get, is the closest number that can be represented in the chosen format.

You have 2 options to get 0.4 as a result in your code:

You can use `Math.Round` to cut the insignificant digits:

```
workedTime = Math.Round(timeSpan.TotalHours, 3)
```

Or you can use `decimal` and divide `TotalMinutes` by 60 yourself:

```
decimal workedTime = (decimal)timeSpan.TotalMinutes / 60;
```

`ToString()` with no parameters or ["G" format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#GFormatString) will automatically round the `double` value to 15 digits.

```
0.3999999999999997.ToString() // "0.4"
0.399999999999997.ToString()  // "0.399999999999997"
```

Comment: I chose to use Math.Round to 4 digits since I know my TimeSpans will never need more than 4 digits (I know this because I explicitly control the input). I admit though, I cannot understand why the developers of the framework (and other languages) cannot make 24/60 = .4 It reminds me of the stories you hear that someone created some flawed methodology 40 years ago and everyone since has followed it...flaws and all.